# JavaScript get permission for Audio.setSinkId

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to change the `sinkId` at an Audio-Element in a chrome app.

Code:

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.setSinkId("communications");
```

I'll get this error:

`DOMException: No permission to use requested device`

So to get the permission I tried to do that:

```js
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio: true
}, (stream) => {
    console.log("stream: ", stream);
}, (error) => {
    console.log("error: ", error);
});
```

But now I get this:

```
error:
NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "InvalidStateError", message: "", constraintName: ""}
```

I don't know, whether

- 'audio' is not available (but actually it should)
- I need a secure connection (but how do I get this at a chrome app?)

Comment: I have the same problem and looked at the docs: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices

the example (which is also not working on Windows 10): https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

And an open issue at github: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/445

It seems to be broken currently..

PS: There is also an Chrome extension which should be able to switch audio outputs here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audiopick/gfhcppdamigjkficnjnhmnljljhagaha
It might contains some interesting code? (haven't looked at it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the example and the chrome extension aren't working on my computer (Windows 8, chrome version 63.0.3239.132), too. Hope it will be fixed soon!

Comment: No "invalid state" error here on Chrome v78, but it's still seemingly broken to have to request an audio input stream to get permissions for audio output.  I added a bounty to your question to hopefully get a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a [mediacapture-output WG](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-output/) and they did define an extension to the `MediaDevices` interface which adds a [`selectAudioOutput()`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-output/#dom-mediadevices-selectaudiooutput) method which takes care of the internal permission requests.
This method would return a *deviceInfo* object from where you can extract the `deviceId` you would pass to `HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId()`.

```
const deviceInfo = await navigator.mediaDevices.selectAudioOuput();
audio_elem.setSinkId(deviceInfo.deviceId);
```

Note also that there is active discussions about renaming this `setSinkId` method to `setAudioOutput`, so it might change again when browsers will start implementing all this.

Firefox 93 starts exposing this method, under the `media.setsinkid.enabled` flag.

---

---

Alternatively there should be a [`Permissions.request()`](https://wicg.github.io/permissions-request/#dom-permissions-request) method, which should accept a *PermissionDescriptor* object which itself should support a [*PermissionName*](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#enumdef-permissionname) of value **`"speaker-selection"`**.

So that would give us

```
 await navigator.permissions.request( { name: "speaker-selection" } );
 const all_devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
 const audio_outs = all_devices.filter( ({ kind }) => kind === "audiooutput" );
 // ...
 audioElem.setSinkId( audio_outs[ n ].deviceId );
```

---

---

But as of today August of 2021, it seems that still no browser supports this.

Chrome (which is the only one currently supporting `MediaElement.setSinkId()`) does expose the `Permission.request()` method under `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`, but they still don't support the *PermissionName* `"speaker-selection"` yet.

So we still need the less than optimal workaround of requesting for the `"microphone"` one instead.

```
(async () => {
  const query = await navigator.permissions.query( { name: "microphone" } );
  switch( query.state ) {
    case "denied": throw new Error('denied');
    case "prompt":
      await queryUserMedia();
      await getListOfDevices();
      break;
    case "granted": await getListOfDevices();
  }
  function queryUserMedia() {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { audio: true } );
  }
  async function getListOfDevices() {
    const all_devs = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    const audioouts = all_devs.filter( ({ kind }) => kind === "audiooutput" );
    const options = audioouts.map( ( dev, index ) => {
      const name = dev.label || ('audio out ' + index );
      return new Option( name , dev.deviceId );
    } );
    sel.append.apply( sel, options );
    sel.onchange = e => aud.setSinkId( sel.value );
  }

})().catch( console.error );
```

[As a fiddle since Stack-Snippets iframes won't allow for the use of the microphone.](https://jsfiddle.net/jhuyc0mb/)

---

Ps: Note that if/when browsers were supporting the specs defined API, then it would even [be possible](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#dom-permissionname-speaker) to [run this code on non-secure contexts](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#allowed-in-non-secure-contexts).

Comment: Bummer!  I was really hoping I was just reading this spec wrong.  In any case, thanks for confirming that it isn't supported today.  I'll stick with `getUserMedia()` for now.

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to a Chromium bug, so we can follow it?  Also, I tossed a bounty on a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/59131286/362536

Comment: Already saw that other question.. Unfortunately I couldn't think of anything better than my poor suggestions in the comments... For crbugs, [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510405) is the one about implementing `request` and `revoke` but I don't think `"speaker"` is tracked anywhere yet (the only mention when [searching for it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=component%3ABlink%3EPermissionsAPI%20speaker) being this [unrelated crbug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=938810))

Comment: The spec now calls this permission `speaker-selection` and it is starting to be implemented (e.g. appears in Firefox 92)

Comment: Ah now I see it, `navigator.mediaDevices.selectAudioOutput` now appears with `media.setsinkid.enabled` flag on. Do you know if there is an umbrella bug we could follow @HamishWillee

Comment: Not as far as I know. There is no evidence of it in Chrome or Webkit right now.