# How can I request user permission for audio on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, audiocontext

I am working on SAAS solution and I need customers to receive notification sounds from the application. Even if they just launched it without any interaction with it. Google has changed Chrome behaviour regarding this aspect and now user is required to click on webpage to get notification sounds. I have found out that it is possible to allow sounds explicitly here:

[image]

and then user should enable sounds explicitly for your websites:

[image]

Now user will not have to click to enable sound notifications. My question: is it possible to request user permission for sound the same way we do it for microphone:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply make your own alert modal. You can feature detect if it is required or not by trying to play your audio while muted

```js
const audio = new Audio( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3' );
audio.muted = true;

const alert_elem = document.querySelector( '.alert' );

audio.play().then( () => {
  // already allowed
  alert_elem.remove();
  resetAudio();
} )
.catch( () => {
  // need user interaction
  alert_elem.addEventListener( 'click', ({ target }) => {
    if( target.matches('button') ) {
      const allowed = target.value === "1";
      if( allowed ) {
        audio.play()
          .then( resetAudio );
      }
      alert_elem.remove();
    }
  } );
} );

document.getElementById( 'btn' ).addEventListener( 'click', (e) => {
  if( audio.muted ) {
    console.log( 'silent notification' );
  }
  else {
    audio.play();
  }
} );

function resetAudio() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.muted = false;
}
```

```css
.alert {
  font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px lightgray;
}
p { margin: 12px; }
.alert .buttons {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p>This webpage would like to play sounds</p>
  <p class="buttons">
    <button value="0">Block</button>
    <button value="1">Allow</button>
  </p>
</div>
<button id="btn">trigger notification</button>
```

---

Ps: note that there is a `"speaker"` value in [Permissions API specs](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#dom-permissionname-speaker), but this one is for allowing devices through `HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId()` method, which is yet another beast. (you can see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854159/javascript-get-permission-for-audio-setsinkid/59260724#59260724) if you are interested in this not yet implemented feature).

Comment: this will force my user to click each time he opens browser, right?

Comment: Only when needed. If they already allowed permanently your website they won't have the message. There is no way to set this "permanent allowance" from web api, so that's the best you can do, which is not so bad...

Comment: Is possible to do the same for Safari and Firefox? They do not fail to play like Chrome do, so the 'catch' code never runs…

Comment: Chrome autoplay policies are unique: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: hey this answer is helpful, but could you explain how to play sounds on autoplay without pressing the button?